# Wrong shortdate format when delphi application is run as service

Tags: delphi, windows-7

We have a delphi application which can also run as a sevice . We have a problem with the shortdate formats while running our application as a service on a Windows 7 machine. Delphi/Win 7 returns a wrong shortdate format. It always returns the "DD-MM-YYYY" format irrespective of the locale we choose . This happens only when we run it as a Service and on win 7! When the application is not run as service we have no issues! 
we tried the workaround of changing and saving the formats twice, but in vain
Any help here?

Comment: Post your code that converts the date to a string.

Comment: @David, yup, I realized that, that's why I disappeared with the comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service will get the locale settings of the user account it runs under. My guess is you are running the service as LOCALSYSTEM. If you configure the service to run as your interactive user then you will get the locale settings you want.

Comment: The default security policies for the local system account are different from the defaults for a "normal" user account. Network access for example is by default not available under the local system account. Depending on requirements in that area, you need to select or create the account under which the service will run with some care.

Answer (score 0):

If your service need some date format then set your format with ShortDateFormat global variable on service create event. When you install windows 7 you chose country and default system formats. After installation you can change Users formats, but not system formats. Maybe with some Registry hackings you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on the user locale for data processing.

If the data has to be processed using a fixed format create an explicit instance of  `TFormatSettings` and use the SysUtils procedures/functions that take a `TFormatSettings` as a second parameter.

For display purposes it's quite the opposite, users expect applications to use their locale settings from the control panel.